# Optimal strategy in three-player number-picking game

Tags: probability, game-theory

Consider a game in which there are three players. Call them Player $1$, Player $2$, and Player $3$. Here are the rules:

- Each player is supposed to select an integer between $1$ and $100$.
- Player $1$'s number is randomly generated. Player $2$ and Player $3$ both know that Player $1$'s number is randomly generated.
- The person with the largest number has to pay the other two people the number that each one of them said (i.e. say Player $1$ picks $5$, Player $2$ picks $70$ and Player $3$ picks $90$. In this case, Player $3$ pays $5$ to Player $1$ and $70$ to Player $2$).

Let's suppose you are Player $3$. Furthermore, suppose that Player $2$ plays optimally. What's the best strategy if you want to maximize profit?

I solved the $n = 2$ (two-player game) case here: [Optimal strategy in probability-based game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411465/optimal-strategy-in-probability-based-game?noredirect=1#comment7016587_3411465)

I want to extend it to $n = 3$, but I can't figure it out. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Wouldnt players 2 and 3 use the same strategy which requires them trumping each other?

Comment: What happens if two players are joint highest?  Does the lowest get half from each, or the full amount from each so double in total?

Comment: @Henry They pick again until everyone has different numbers.

Comment: @Ehz - that does not look like a desirable rule: If players 2 and 3 have pure strategies which are identical, they would always choose the same numbers as each other. So you would never have everyone having different numbers

Comment: Okay, let's say that they get the full amount from each (so double in total)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are only 2 players in this game. Player 1 does not choose a strategy between a set of strategies.

This game could be represented as $\mathcal{G}(X_1,X_2,H_1,H_2)$, where $X_i=[0,100]\cap\Bbb{Z}$, for i={1,2} and:

$$H_i(x_1,x_2)=
\begin{cases}
E(Z_i),  & \text{if $x_i> x_j$} \\
\frac{E(Z_i)}{2},  & \text{if $x_i= x_j$} \\\\
x_i, & \text{$x_i<x_j$}
\end{cases}$$

Now suposse $x_j<x_i$:  $ E(Z_i\mid x_i > Y)=-(\frac{x_i+1}{2}+x_j)$

$E(Z_i) = \left(\frac{1 - x_i}{100}\right)\left(\frac{x_i + 1}{2}+x_j\right) + \left(\frac{100x_i - x_i^2}{100}\right)=\frac{-3x_i^2-2x_ix_j+200x_i+2x_j+1}{200}$

The new optimum is $x_i=33-2x_j$, for  $ i,j=\left\lbrace1,2\right\rbrace$, $j\neq i$.

The solution to that system is $(11,11)$, which is the Nash equilibrium of $\mathcal{G}$.

Edit: Now assuming that if two of them tie, they will pay half. Notice that if they tie, the payment function had the same optimum as the original.
This solution is consistent with the previous game, if both of them tie, they will have to pay $\frac{x+x}{2}=x$ to each other, so the benefits will be $0$.

Comment: If they both loose (loose $x_j$), $H_i(x_1,x_2)=E(Z_i)$, if $x_i \ge x_j$, so the equilibrium will be the same. But it isn't consistent with the original game (if they tied, the benefit was $0$).
The case they both win (gain $x_i$), had the same problem, and besides, it isn't naturally, who will pay them?