# Optimal strategy for dice game against different types of players

Tags: probability, game-theory, expected-value

The following is an interview question.

> Question: Given $2$ players, you are player $1$ and another player (player 2).
>
> $(i)$ Both players select a number between 1 and 100 inclusively and the one who tells the bigger number has to pay the lower number to the other player. If both numbers are the same, then player $1$ needs to pay the number to player $2.$ The player $2$ says a random number between 1 and 100. What is the optimal strategy ?
>
> $(ii)$ Now, we assume that player $2$ is smart. Same rules above apply. Which strategy to beat him ?

Since player $2$ selects number randomly, player $2$ has expected value of choosing $50.5.$ So, player $1$ should choose $50$.

For $(ii),$ I have no idea how to start at all.

player $1$ can always pick number $1$ to win. But that is not optimal.

Comment: This was already asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411680. (I intended to answer that question but haven't gotten around to it yet.)

Comment: a) Where you say "the bigger number" in $(ii)$, I think you mean the biggest number? b) You mention the lack of specification for what happens in a tie in $(i)$. This also applies to $(ii)$ -- how shall we deal with it there? (The same problem occurred in the other question I linked to above, so it seems there's a badly specified version of the problem out there being used in interviews...)

Comment: @joriki Indeed, I also realize that the question does not address tie situation. I added this after the question.

Comment: Where? I mentioned that you mentioned this specifically for $(i)$, but I don't see where you address it for $(ii)$.

Comment: @joriki Ah. I didn't mention for part (ii)....

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. So are you not going to define what happens for ties in case $(ii)$? It's also not clear to me what you mean for $(i)$ by "both cases". I see more than two ways of resolving ties, even for $(i)$: We have at least the options of Player $1$ paying, Player $2$ paying, neither player paying and both players paying, and the payments could be full or half.

Comment: Also, it still says "bigger number" in $(ii)$; you didn't respond to my request for clarification on that. Are you aware that there's an edit link under the question that allows you to clarify the question?

Comment: Your edit hasn't resolved anything. You're no longer even mentioning the tie problem, and it still says "bigger number" in $(ii)$, where it's unclear what you mean by that (given that there are three numbers involved). Why are you not responding to my requests for clarification?

Comment: @joriki I have no idea how to edit (ii) to make it clear. I changed it to a completely different question now.